# UploadiFve OnCancel event - which variable returns the file_id selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadifive

I am using UploadiFive v1.1.2.

I use the `onCancel` event to detect a file that has been cancelled in the queue. Is there a returned value to tell me which file was chosen?

I currently use file.name which is not ideal as per below.

```
'onCancel': function(file) {
    $('#id_' + file.name.slice(0,-4)).remove();
}
```

Comment: DO you need the file name on select?

Comment: No, I don't. Just the file queue id (numerical)

Comment: You can set the file queue id yourself `'queueID'  : 'some_file_queue'`

Comment: I have done that 'queueID' : 'queue'

Comment: But how do I retrieve the queue ID from the onCancel event?

Comment: You already know the queue id,then why bother to retrieve it?